# Solution of a polynomial boson problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-electrodynamics, anharmonic-oscillators

I was reading about anharmonicity that can be added to the harmonic oscillator model and I got myself wondering whether it is possible and whether there is a general method to solve (I mean diagonalize) a general polynomial problem with creation annihilation operators provided the problem is Hermitian. I am thinking at something like this:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k}\sum_{n}\gamma_{k,n}\left(a^{\dagger\;n}a^{k-n}+a^{\dagger\;k-n}a^{n}\right)\rightarrow\rightarrow(transformations)\rightarrow\rightarrow \sum_{k}\omega_{k}a^{\dagger\;k}a^{k}
\end{equation}
Thank you very much for your help